# Get QUERY_STRING using python

Tags: python

Struggling to see why this isn't working:

```
import MySQLdb
import cgi, cgitb
import os
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from cgi import parse_qs, escape

def index(req):

    d = parse_qs(os.environ['QUERY_STRING'])

    dtbox = d.get('dt', [''])[0]
    tmbox = d.get('tm', [''])[0]
```

The script returns a KeyError: QUERY_STRING

I can see the URL which is:

```
http://myserver/currentcost.py?dt=2013-09-10&tm=00
```

I'm simply lost!

Comment: err, what are you trying to do with the string "QUERY_STRING"? Is it one of the environment variables found in your machine?

Comment: How are you running this script - CGI, mod_python, mod_wsgi, what?

Comment: @Daniel. I'm submitting a form via Ajax and the mod_python script is supposedly getting the URL. Everything I've read or been pushed towards in other posts suggests the QUERY_STRING variable is set in the environment when the form is submitted. I've never known such a simple task be so hard to resolve!

Comment: Why are you using mod_python, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
req.subprocess_env['QUERY_STRING']
```

This is how it's supposed to work with mod_python; the way in which you were doing it before seems to be meant for CGI.

Also, as a side note, I think it would be nicer to do:

```
d.get('dt', [None])[0]
```

instead of

```
d.get('dt', [''])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

d = parse_qs(os.environ.get('QUERY_STRING', ''))

This worked for me because I had the same problem.  After researching for a while I came across this solution and everything seemed to work fine after that.